# template array in c++ with 3 different definitions

Tags: c++

I want to make an Array with 3 differnt definitions. More specifically i want an array like this : A[i,j]=(string, int, bool
                                  string, int, bool)
I am trying to make a template but i am confused.

Comment: Can you give an example of how this would be used?

Comment: The syntax `A[i,j]` is not supported in C++.

Comment: If you have access to C++11, [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) might be worth a look. Otherwise your exact requirements are unclear.

Comment: "i am confused."  Yeah, me too.

Comment: I want an array which i will fill with the datas of o product.
The user will give me a discription, the price and if the product is new or not(true/false) and i want to put it in an array of unknow lines and 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use templates you can make an array of structs:

```
template <class A, class B, class C>
struct Vars{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
};

//declaring the types of the template you want to use
Vars <std::string, int, bool> *ray;

//initializing array in heap
ray = new Vars<std::string, int, bool>[SIZE];
```

Alternatively, If you have decided you always want to use this combination you can much more easily do this:

```
struct Vars{
    std::string a;
    int b;
    bool c;
};

Vars *ray = new Vars[SIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a regular class that implements this behavior. 
Something like this:

```
class specialArray {
    char *** strings;
    int **integers;
    bool **booleans;
    public:
        specialArray(int rows, int columns, unsigned char data[]) {
            //initialize arrays to correct sizes
            /*add a special values, such as 253, 254, 255 (which are not 
            used for chars, bools, or strings (since the operating system 
            takes control of memory locations 253, 254, 255)) every time the 
            type of the array changes*/
            /*Use the special values to determine which array each byte of 
            information should go to (and use casts). Arrays which are not 
            filled at each index should be set to 0 at that position*/
            /*create a function access(int loc) to obtain a value. In this 
            function, check each of the three arrays until one of the arrays 
            at that index value is not 0. Return a byte array.*/
            /*Implementing this in c++ is extremely inefficient, by the 
            way as you can see by the enormous amount of code this 
            requires*/
        }
        //do something similar for operator=()
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean about 253, 254, 255 addresses

Comment: Those numbers are used in order to distinguish between data that should be read as bools, ints, or strings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, arrays -AFAIK- can have only one datatype. However you can use struct/classes pair two different types then make a one dimensional array out of it.

Check this code illustration, and check if it is what you are looking for.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct MyArray
{
    T   a;
    U   b;
};

int main()
{
    MyArray<int,bool> arr[2];

    arr[0] = {30,1};

    cout << arr[0].a;
    cout << " : ";
    cout << arr[0].b;
}
```

You may also use pair, tuples and/or vectors... etc. It all depends on your vision and needs.